# ¿Como se usa el timestamp de laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, timestamp

Lo que sucede es que cree un nuevo formulario de producto y quiero que sea igual que el formulario de registro que entrega laravel, es decir, que al momento de insertar el producto, se llene automáticamente el created_at y updated_at (ya cree las columnas), entonces quería saber de que método lo hace registro, ya que si reviso los controllers no encuentro relaciones con el timestamp.

Comment: mejora por favor tu pregunta y añade por ejemplo la estructura de una de tus migraciones

Comment: Debes mejorar tus preguntas como dice @shadow. Mira [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506712/inserting-created-at-data-with-laravel) encontraras una pregunta similar que te resultara útil. Tambien te dejo otro link [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) con mas documentación para que la mires. Saludos!

Comment: Debes poner el código que tengas hecho, así no podemos ayudarte fácilmente, Saludos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matias Muñoz:

Creo que si entendi bien tu pregunta la respuesta es:

Por Default, **Laravel** y en específico **Eloquent** esperan que las columnas **created_at** y **updated_at** existan en tu tabla. Por lo que al guardar un elemento en tu base de datos usando Laravel, este campo es llenado automáticamente.

Si tu no quieres que los campos estén por defecto los puedes configurar en el mismo modelo.

Si, por ejemplo no deseas usar un $timestamps puedes configurarlo en la clase de tu modelo respectivo:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Si, por otro lado necesitas customizar tus campos, a como los tienes en tus migraciones lo puedes hacer asi:

```
//Ejemplos:
const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';
const UPDATED_AT = 'last_update';
```

Si, deseas una respuesta con un ejemplo en concreto podrías subir tu migraciòn y la de tus modelos y controladores, para asi darte un ejemplo de como se comporta Laravel.
Espero haber sido de utilidad.
Saludos

Puedes también revisar la documentaciòn de Laravel directamente en su [página web](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), donde esta toda la documentaciòn al respecto.

Comment: No es necesario llenar un campo en tu formulario que sea específico a los timestamps, al momento de enviar la informaciòn desde tu vista a la base de datos a travès del controlador, este automáticamente guardará los campos timestamps, si están en tu tabla respectiva.

Comment: Gracias compañero! jaja sin querer tenia timestam en false, al ponerlo en true me actuó sin problemas!

Comment: De nada compa, apruebe mi respuesta para que le sirva a la comunidad. 
Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que tienes que hacer es un `Model`, y ya con él haces algo así:

```
$model = new Model();
$model->variable1 = $var1;
$model->variable2 = $var2;
$model->save();
```

Y ya con el `save()` se guardan los `timestamps`.

Comment: digo y si leiste que lo quiere guardar de manera automática?

Comment: Si no es de esa manera entonces debería meterle mano a la tabla, poniendo como por default, en esas columnas, que sea `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación de Laravel viene el método "Create", el cual lleva como parametro un objeto con las llaves relacionadas a tus campos

```
$flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

En el cual se asignara automáticamente las fechas de "created_at" y "updated_at".

También existe el método "insert()" que revise el mismo parámetro pero a diferencia este no generara automático las fechas

Comment: Ya si no buscabas esto, a lo mejor lo quieres por bases de datos, en tu migración al momento de crearla tendrás que agregarle 'CURRENT_TIMSTAMP' al momento de crear la tabla a ambos campos 

`$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));` 

o tambien esta esta forma la cual viene en la documentación de Laravel

`$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();`